# What is the difference between having curly brackets, parentheses and without brackets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

Which is the common way to introduce a ref in React, and how will it differ with curly brackets, parentheses and without brackets?

Line 1:

```
buttonRef={n => {this.loadMoreBtn = n}}
```

Line 2:

```
buttonRef={n => (this.loadMoreBtn = n)}
```

Line: 3

```
buttonRef={n => this.loadMoreBtn = n}
```

Comment: ignore me - must be a react thing

Comment: @shubam it seems related but it actually isnt.

Comment: In terms of using ref, you can use any one of the above syntaxes since all you need is to assign the ref to a class instance variable, however the difference between the first two is about implicit and explicit return

Comment: @JonasW.  I added more explanation about it in my comment

Comment: Let me know if you still don't understand the difference after referring the duplicate and reading my comment

Comment: You can use any of the syntaxes, what you should know is `ref` takes a `function` which is called with `node` as a parameter.